# Multiple assignments in SQL - correct syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Multiple assignments in SQL. The one variable form works and I have extended to use two variables: A and B. But I cannot see how I would extend the format. The following is what I am trying.

```
SELECT TOP 1 @MYA = A; @MYB = CB FROM WHERE X='MYX' ORDER BY X Total select @MYA @MYB
```

Here is my original statement:

```
   SELECT TOP 1 @MYA = A FROM WHERE X='MYX' ORDER BY X Total select @MYA
```

How can I return two variables or more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use commas:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @MYA = A, @MYB = CB
FROM
WHERE X='MYX'
ORDER BY X, Total;

select @MYA, @MYB;
```

The `;` goes at the *end* of the statement.

Comment: This seemed to work if I put a comma between '@MYA @MYB'